# errors in using JavaFX

Tags: eclipse, builder, scene

I try to use SceneBuilder inside Eclipse in order to create a first easy example of graphic interface but I had this error that I cannot solve.

I created the Controller Class through the Eclipse function.

#### Error

```
    *xception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at ProvaGrafica2.start(ProvaGrafica2.java:29)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
    Exception running application ProvaGrafica2*
```

#### Code

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProvaGrafica2 extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start (Stage stage) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("prova");

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\u5ex\\Desktop\\eclipse\\Grafica2\\src\\a.fxml");
    if (file.exists())
        System.out.println("il file esiste");


    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\u5ex\\Desktop\\eclipse\\Grafica2\\src\\a.fxml"));
    Scene scene=new Scene (root);
    stage.setTitle("Login");
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();

}
```

Comment: Your `getResource` is returning `null` because your resource path isn't valid.

Comment: Hi Greg, why it is not valid? What should I put? tks

Comment: Resource paths are relative to the class, use '/' not '\' and can't use `C:`

Comment: I put "/a.fxml" also before, but the error is the same. do I need to create special  "resources" or something like that? I put the fxml file in the class directory, is it correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)

Answer (score 1):

In your case it should be enough to shorten your getResource call to `getClass().getResource("a.fxml")`. At least I hope so because without actually trying it I would not bet on it :-)

Comment: Hi , I tryed using only "a.fxml" but the error is the same. any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

@mipa's answer is correct, you should use `getClass().getResource("a.fxml")`, but here's a little more in-depth about this: `getClass().getResource(...)` is supposed to be used for files inside the `src` folder, which files that will end up inside your final JAR. However, the path passed to `getResource()` is not relative to the `src` folder but to your class file. So, if your .java file is:

```
src/com/package/YourClass.java
```

Then `getClass().getResouce("a.fxml")` would refer to:

```
src/com/package/a.fxml
```

If you want relative to the `src` directory, start the path with a slash, i.e. `getClass().getResouce("/a.fxml")`.
Also you should note that to load a file that is anywhere on the disk (eg. picked by the user), you should use this instead:

```
File file = new File("your/path/here/file.fxml");
FXMLLoader.load(file.toURI().toURL());
```

Comment: Hi @Chaoz , thanks fot the answer , but I tried with your suggestion ("a.fxml" and "/a.fxml" ) butthe situation is the same.

Comment: the a.fxml file is in the src directory and also in Eclipe I see it . any other suggestion?